# Mouse trapped in current window in Studio 18.04

Tags: mouse

I am running Ubuntu Studio 18.04 “Bionic Beaver” upgraded with all the available patches.Mouse clicks are not sent to other windows or even the system bar. Hovering the mouse over e.g. the 'computer' control will bring up the text equivalent, but neither left nor right clicks work. The same effect is observed under multiple applications.

Even when an application opens, e.g. a file upload dialog, the mouse does not interact with the dialog box in any way although manual selection, tab and enter allow its use.

When I manage to run more than one application (challenging due to not being able to access the program menu, but possible through e.g. spawning a second firefox session), I can sometimes switch between applications on the system bar with the mouse and always with alt-tab, and the mouse will work correctly in both windows.

Any suggestions for debugging or returning my system to usability would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: I have now bought a new SSD drive, downloaded and reinstalled Ubuntu Studio 18.04.
Same problem.
I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu Studio 19.10 same problem.
If there is no keystroke combination to close an app, I am trapped in that app until I switch to a console and close that app. Whereupon I can open another app.

Comment: The problem was having two mice. One USB, one bluetooth.
Apparently this is no longer possible.

Comment: On further investigation it appears that it is the wireless mouse causing the issue, as the USB mouse by iteslf works fine, but plugging the wiireless mouse in alone and rebooting yields the same symptoms.

The problematic wireless mouse is a Razer Atheris identified with lsusb as 1532:0062